# Combining fields in Splunk alert rules

Tags: regex, splunk, victorops

In VictorOps' Alert Rule Engine it's easy to check whether a single field exists. 
E.g. `when azure.context.portalLink matches * using Wildcard` checks if this field exists 
(and allows us to set up an Azure portal link in the annotations).

However, there are three fields that may contain this portal link:
[image]

and these have similar implementations. Would it be possible to check something like

```
When field1|field2|field3 matches * using Wildcard ?
```

Comment: Hi Casper, As the feature ask is about VictorOps' Alert Rule Engine so it would be better to tag VictorOps related tags or reach to VictorOps support.

Comment: I agree, but there are no VictorOps tags at this moment :D

Comment: I just added it for you. Just FYI, [creation privilege is awarded at 1500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

Comment: As this is a new tag now so I am not sure if someone who is SME in VictorOps would actively check Stack Overflow or not so I also would recommend you to check other options like reaching out VictorOps support directly.